# How to make Matlab understand where a (to-be-folded) code section begins and ends

Tags: matlab, syntax

I would like certain sections (rows) in my Matlab script to be foldable as a section code (cell). These rows do not necessarily always have an "end" keyword terminating them, and so I'd like to define myself where a code section begins and ends.

However, it seems that Matlab only understands the beginnings (marked with %%), and not the endings, of such code sections. Matlab seems to look for various other clues (such as code keywords like 'case') as the end of a code section, and ignores % or %% symbols, which I inserted in order to tell Matlab this is where I'd like the cell to end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under *Preferences > Editor/Debugger > Code Folding* there is a tick box for *sections*. If you tick this then you can use the `%%` to fold sections.

However, you should note that the sections (i.e. `%%`) have a use to the editor which is to allow you to easily run only the code in that section and not the entire script. So if you use `%%` liberally around your code just for code folding (and also it won't be nestable), then you might loose this capability.

Comment: Thanks. That tickbox is already checked (which is why I can, as I said, fold code sections). The problem is that matlab is confused about where *the end* of a folded section is, and does not regard a second % or %% as indicator of a section's ending.

Comment: It will regard the second `%%` as the start of the next section and thus implicitly ends the previous section. A regular comment `%` will ignored of course. Can you post some example code where the folding doesn't work on the sections (i.e. where it ignores the second `%%`)?

Comment: that's the thing though - what you say assumes that sections of code that are to be folded are necessarily continuous, whereas I'd like to be able to fold a section that starts with a %% and ends with another %%, then have some intervening code, then another foldable section, etc. Is that possible?

Comment: the intervening code (middle section) is very long so it'd be useful to be able to fold it..

Comment: I'm not understanding the problem, lets say I have 10 lines of code. On lines, 20, 30, 80 and 90 I type `%%`. I can now fold lines 20 - 30 and also fold lines 80-90 and lines 30 - 80 will remain unfolded. Sure you *can* fold them, but you also could just not...

Comment: right that makes sense I guess I just got a bit confused, thanks :)